# How to run a nested puppet module?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, puppet

I have a relatively simple manual task that I am trying to automate using Puppet.

Steps I want to perform via Puppet:

- Copy tarball over from Puppetmaster to several server 'client' nodes.
- Untar the tarball on said server node.
- Execute, one at a time, each of the installation agents 'install.sh' file.
- Clean up (remove) original tarball bundle.

I was hoping not to have one huge init.pp file, but somehow have it a bit modular so that I could have a different class (?) for each of the agents that need to be installed on the 'client' server nodes.

How would I go about doing this? Examples are preferred so I can learn.

I tried something like this (to do the initial copy, untar and cleanup), but it's not exactly 'pretty'.

```
class dd_bundle {
  file { '/opt/apps':
    ensure => 'directory',
  }

  file { '/opt/apps/dd-app-bundle.tar.gz':
    source => 'puppet:///modules/dd_bundle/dd-app-bundle.tar.gz',
    ensure => file,
    replace => false,
    mode => '0664';
  }

  exec { 'tar -xf /opt/apps/dd-app-bundle.tar.gz':
    cwd => '/opt/apps',
    path => ['/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin',],
  }

  tidy { '/opt/apps/dd-app-bundle.tar.gz': }

}
```

It would be nice if there was a way I could just somehow have a way to have individual classes and then add them to the init.pp file, then I could make adjustments to each individual class (application) for doing its install part.

Just trying to figure out a streamlined way to make a manual process be automated.

Comment: You can make this working, but it is not the puppet way. With puppet, all installation actions should be inside puppet, not in a smart `install.sh`. When you do want to use your install.sh, perhaps place your tar bare on a shared location or a website and copy/download it in your install.sh.

Comment: The intent is to be able to stand up a series of puppet client nodes and install several 'monitoring' agents on them like ESET, BelManage, AlertLogic, to satisfy our SRE team needs. I thought of trying something where I could have something like a node 'server-name' { include belmanage-package, include eset-package, include alertlogic-package } in a site.pp file and have each of the above 'includes' be modules that could be used as needed. Is it not possible to do something like this in Puppet?

Comment: This question is pretty broad.  Here at SO, we generally want tightly focused, narrowly scoped questions.

Comment: Note well that Puppet is not designed to be a script runner, and it is pretty awkward for that role. If that's really what you want, then you could consider looking at its "Bolt" companion system, which might serve you better there.  The primary paradigm of Puppet proper is that you define *what* should be included in client machines' configuration, and Puppet works out the how.  And enforces it on every run.

Comment: At the moment, all of the applications are installed manually. I am trying to find an automated solution so I won't have keep doing the manual steps. I am at the point now to see if Puppet or Ansible would be the better choice (not much of a developer) so just trying to see which one has the easier way of deploying the applications and can handle things like an if/else statement for checking to see if the application is already installed or not before attempting to install.